# Laravel 5 store session in database/redis

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to use database (currently, MySQL) to store session. But, when I tried to config, table **sessions** still has no record.

In file *config/session.php* when I change `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),`

1. to `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),`
2. or `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'redis'),`

What should I change for `'connection' => null,`?

I tried:

1. `'connection' => 'mysql',` with *mysql* is configured in *app/database.php*
2. `'connection' => 'database.connections.mysql',`
3. `'connection' => Config::get('database.connections.mysql'),` got *class not found* error

Comment: What is in your `.env` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is specify the right driver in the environment file, and generate the schema as outlined in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#database-sessions).

This line:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database')
```

This is telling the config to get the `SESSION_DRIVER` variable from your environment file, and use `database` as a default. I can only assume you have forgotten to update your `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot `.env` file. :(

Answer (score 0):

I hade to change SESSION_DRIVER=database in .env file
config/session.php changes didn't work for me