# How to get session remember after login in laravel 5?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I start to work with my project using laravel 5. I realized that it work fine in my local directory with session after I login to my site, But I just know that I got problem when I hosted my project to server. After I login each time, the session could not remember that cause the problem to me.

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $hit = 0;

    if(Request::ajax()){
        $pw = Request::input('pw');
        if(!empty($pw)){
            $admin_pass = AdminPassword::first(['admin_pass']);
            $ip_address = Request::ip();
            if(!empty($admin_pass) && trim($admin_pass->admin_pass) == trim($pw)){
                if(Auth::attempt(['username' => Request::input('username'), 'password' => Request::input('password'),'status'=>1])){
                    try{
                        $user = Auth::user();
                        $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $user->login_ip = $ip_address;
                        $user->save();
                        $permissions = Auth::user()->permission;
                        if(!empty($permissions) && count($permissions) >0){
                            session(['ROLE_PERMISSION'=>$permissions]);
                        }
                        $failed = FailedLogin::whereRaw('ip_address = INET_ATON(\''.$ip_address.'\')')->first();
                        if(!empty($failed)){
                            $failed->delete();
                        }
                    }catch (\Exception $ex){}
                    $url = Request::session()->pull('url.intended', '/');
                    return ['url'=>$url,'msg'=>'Successfully.','status'=>true,'hit'=>$hit];
                }else{
                    $hit = $this->updateFailedLogin($ip_address,Request::input('username'));
                }
            }else{
                $hit = $this->updateFailedLogin($ip_address,Request::input('username'));
            }
        }
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
    return ['url'=>'','msg'=>'Try again.','status'=>false,'hit'=>$hit];
}
```

Please help me out from this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check config/auth.php settings? And then if the new environment is set up correctly according to it.

Answer (score 1):

If this works perfectly locally and not only its probably one of two things.
1) you need to set permissions on your storage folder to be writable.
2) when you login locally on the browser and it saves your cookie, if you try to log in online it logs you out locally because its the same cookie basically but point to different domains. So you probably should use different browsers if you want to work locally and online at the same time

Answer (score 1):

**Use below code**

```
 setInterval(function(){
    $.get('/my/ping/route');
 }, 1000 * 60);

.ajaxError()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is Session:save(); It  solved my problem where session has not been carried over when redirecting user to payment gateway.

From what I heard it is caused by some interruption in HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

If the error logs in **storage/logs** don't give any clues about issues such as directory permissions, check your **.env** file on your server for the **SESSION_DRIVER** variable that is loaded in  **config/session.php** to make sure you have the right persistence mechanism based on your server configuration (file, cookie, database, apc, memcached, redis, etc.).

If that doesn't help, check the **config/session.php** file. I've seen someone set the lifetime property to **0** thinking that this would make sessions indefinite, but in reality it caused the issue that you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Please check how you are storing your session.

By default laravel uses file-based ( `storage/framework/sessions` ), make sure the directory is **writeable**.

Answer (score 0):

- firstly your server settings you must check it. check the storage folder's permission. (`sudo chmod -R 777 storage`)
- if it is not fixed. then clear browser cache, and logout your local application and try to login again. maybe you can broke the codes after set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

1)Set the folder permissions
2)Clear the cache and try login again. Enable error reporting for debug so the you can check the clear log.

refer: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/starting-session-after-authebtication

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your project, may be you dont have the right filesystem permissions. Use the session database driver instead.

Refer to [Laravel 5 store session in database/redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598326/laravel-5-store-session-in-database-redis#29598424).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do,
you should try this:

```
Session::put('url.intended', '/')
```